# Catch Exceptions Application Wide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way of overriding default Exception handling (default rescue), so that I can write custom logic there, for example sending stacktrace to our Slack channel.

Basically I want to make something what NewRelic does with their gem: https://github.com/newrelic/rpm but more local version of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you could do is instrument all error raising using a TracePoint:

```
trace = TracePoint.new(:raise) do |tp|
    myLogger.log [tp.lineno, tp.event, tp.raised_exception]
end

trace.enable
```

Using traces used to cause significant code slowdown. I think the new API in ruby 2.0 reduced the slowdown notably. According to my naive benchmark:

```
count = 10_000_000


t = Time.now
count.times do |i|
  begin
    0 / 0
  rescue
  end
end
puts "trial 1: #{Time.now - t}"


t = Time.now
count.times do |i|
  "hi"
  begin
    0 / 0
  rescue
  end
end
puts "trial 2: #{Time.now - t}"


trace = TracePoint.new(:raise) do |tp|
  "hi"
end
trace.enable

t = Time.now
count.times do |i|
  begin
    0 / 0
  rescue
  end
end
puts "trial 3: #{Time.now - t}"

#=>trial 1: 10.110471094
#=>trial 2: 9.971755759
#=>trial 3: 11.608365399
```

Tracepoint only adds 1 second (or 10%) slowdown in 10,000,000 executions of raise. That being said, TracePoint still isn't considered a "production-worthy technique" because it *does* add overhead and can be hard to predict (eg there are a lot of obscure exceptions in ruby).

If you're wondering how new relic manages to instrument code without overhead:

```
...
class_eval <<-EOC
  def #{with_method_name}(*args, &block)
    perform_action_with_newrelic_trace(#{argument_list.join(',')}) do
      #{without_method_name}(*args, &block)
     end
  end
EOC
...
```

It uses several hundred lines of meta-programming to capture specific methods, deconstruct them, and redefine them with instrumentation inside. This technique requires a lot of code and (I would assume) extra memory and time at start-up, but has the advantage of no additional overhead once the methods are assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in **application_controller.rb**

```
rescue_from Exception, with: :rescue500 if Rails.env.production?

rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found unless Rails.env.development?



     def record_not_found
        render json: {code: 404, errors: ["Record not found"]}, status: 404
      end

      def rescue404
        render json: {code: 404, errors: ["No round matches"]}, status: 404
      end

      def rescue500(ex)
        Rails.logger.error("\n\nEXCEPTION: #{ex.inspect}\n")
        Rails.logger.info(ex)
        render json: {code: 500, errors: [ex.message] }, status: 500
      end
```

Comment: It does the thing, yes. But it won't catch all the exceptions Application-Wide, for example in rake tasks. Shouldn't there be a way of setting it in initialiser, or somehow not in Rails settings, but in Ruby, by overriding default exceptions behaviour

Comment: If you override it in ruby, how would you be able to upgrade to the latest releases of ruby? moroever you have mentioned you wanted to do custom things, better I would suggest you to find all the exceptions that could happen and rescue them like above as I mentioned

Comment: Ok, but NewRelic gem somehow manages to handle errors Ruby-wide, and they don't use rescue_from